# Element 'Chart' is not a known element - dotnetCHARTING

Tags: asp.net, dll, charts

I am using dotnetCHARTING: the dll is installed in the GAC and referenced in my web.config (all versions appear to match). The project has a reference to the dll.

web.config:

```
<add assembly="dotnetCHARTING, Version=5.3.3540.17054, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af2cd47db69d93bd"/>
```

The site code compiles ok, but all aspx pages using the charting library complain that the Chart tag does not exist (warning that it might be a compile error). The aspx pages do not render the charts.

Each page has a reference to the assembly:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="dotnetCHARTING" Namespace="dotnetCHARTING" TagPrefix="dotnetCHARTING" %>
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Thanks a lot for any help - I'm quite desperate to get this resolved.

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, next article explains everything.
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q261123.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must download and install MsChart from Microsoft

Here's the download link:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en